# What are the requirements of a new computer to run code?

Tags: laptop

My brother is getting a new laptop and wants to get into coding. I just need to know the specs of the type of system needed to just run code, as in stuff like the processor, RAM and anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he is just getting into coding, any computer will do. At the beginning, the tasks are very simple for the computer and you wouldn't see a difference between an intel celeron or a xeon.

Once he gets to an advanced state, I would consider a more powerfull computer, but not before.

Answer (score 0):

While I would echo what A.Barth says about 'any computer will do', I would just caution that you don't want a completely crap computer.

You don't need a super powerful machine, or a good GPU etc.

However, as programming does require a quick feedback loop, it's incredibly tedious if you're having to wait a couple of seconds for things to run etc.

That said - I'm a professional web developer, and I was able to get by fine with a second hand laptop that I bought for about $US500 a couple of years ago.

At a minimum I would suggest that the computer has a SSD, at least four cores,  at least 8GB RAM, preferably 16, and if they're running Windows, use Windows 10.

There are plenty of second hand (Look at ex-commercial) laptops you can get for around $US500 that fit this.